# Can't get a substring after String.split()?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I am making a Java program, but I've run into a problem.

First, let me show you the code:

```
if (file.exists()){
        for (String s : DFileLoader.getMethod(pathToSaveAs)){
            if (s.startsWith("playerSendMessage%$%@@")){
                pSmsgc.setSelected(true);

            }else{
                pSmsg.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        if (DFileLoader.getMethod(pathToSaveAs).size() <= 0){
            pSmsg.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }else{
        pSmsg.setEnabled(false);
    }
    pSmsgc.setFont(fDisp);
    pSmsgc.setBounds(new Rectangle(50, 135, 140, 30));
    pSmsg.setBounds(new Rectangle(175, 135, 150, 30));
    pSmsgc.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (pSmsgc.isSelected()) pSmsg.setEnabled(true);
            else pSmsg.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    pane.add(pSmsgc);


    if (file.exists()){
        for (String s : DFileLoader.getMethod(pathToSaveAs)){
            if (s.startsWith("playerSendMessage%$%@@")){
                String[] d = s.split("%$%@@");
                String text;
                if (d.length <= 1) text = "";
                else text = d[1];
                pSmsg.setText(text);
            }
        }
    }
    pane.add(pSmsg);
```

Here are some things to know about this:

1. When I use "getMethod(path)", its just returning a String List (List) which includes each line of the TXT file.
2. pSmsgc is a JCheckBox and pSmsg is a JTextField.
3. I have it so when the box is not checked, the text field is grayed out, which works fine.
4. If the file has a line that starts with "playerSendMessage%$%@@", the box will be checked, which works.

The thing that isn't working is where it sets the text field's text to the second substring of that line.

For example, the file's line could be "playerSendMessage%$%@@Hello!". This would cause the box to be checked, and the field to says "Hello!"

Everything works except for the part where the field says the text.

It might be just a simple thing that I am overlooking, or maybe not. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You might try running your code in a debugger or adding println() statements to see how far your code gets, and what the values are of a given variable. ... 1) Does the execution get inside the if(file.exists()) statement block? 2) Does it get inside the for(String s: ...) loop? 3) Does it get inside the if(s.startsWith...) statement? 4) What is the size and values inside d? 5) What is the final value of the 'text' variable just before the pSmg.setText() line?

Comment: I'm curious what would happen if you try making the regex argument "playerSendMessage%$%@@"?

Comment: With lines like something-dot-functionOfSomething, we might benefit from seeing a larger part of your code.

Comment: @CalebWoodman The DFileLoader.getMethod just returns a String list of the text from a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file's line name contains the character `'$'` which means *end of a line* on  [**RegExp** patterns.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

So the solution would be to escaping with `\\` the character in conflict with RegExp syntax like this:

```
String[] d = s.split("%\\$%@@");
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for this! I just got rid of the $, because I didn't need it, and it worked!

Comment: You're welcome =), and don't confuse the word 'parameter' with 'substring' !!.